# What does struts do differently when talking about REST

Tags: rest, struts2

Hi I am finding it hard to find information on this topic, but wondering if someone can answer this one for me.  I understand the advantages of using REST with resources, but how is it useful to implement REST with struts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but it's "useful" particularly if you already have an S2 app. If you *just* need to expose a RESTful API you can still use S2, but there are many other options like Jersey, Spring, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about how it can be implemented with Struts2?

There are multiple ways:

- Just use the [Struts2 Rest Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/docs/rest-plugin.html)
- Define your actions with the convention plugin and write an interceptor like in this [example](https://github.com/apache/struts/pull/25)
- Use the [RestActionMapper](https://struts.apache.org/docs/restfulactionmapper.html)
- There are also some third party rest plugins available.  https://java.net/projects/s2restplugins/pages/Home